# Optional use of base constructor C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to figure out OOP in C#. I have an abstract superclass `Shape` that has a constructor, that takes an array of class `Point`, and 2 optional parameters: `color` and `filling`.

```
internal abstract class Shape
    {
        protected string color;
        protected bool filled;
        protected Point[] Points;

        public Shape(Point[] points, string color, bool filled)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.filled = filled;
            if (points.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("A shape can't be created with less than a 3 points");
            }
            this.Points = points;
        }

        public Shape(Point[] points)
        {
            this.color = "green";
            this.filled = true;
            if (points.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("A shape can't be created with less than a 3 points");
            }
            this.Points = points;
        }
    }
```

`Point` is another class that has fields for `x` and `y` and basically represents a point on a coordinates scale. Can be created with 2 numbers for x and y, or with another instance of `Point`

```
internal class Point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        public Point( int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Point(Point test)
        {
            this.x = test.x;
            this.y = test.y;

        }
    }
```

Now I need to create another class `Triangle`, inherited from `Shape` that can take not an array of `Point`, but 3 separate instances of `Point`, and then optionally take `color` and `filled`.

So, I was trying to do something like this:

```
internal class Triangle : Shape
    {
        Point point1;
        Point point2;
        Point point3;
        public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3, string color, bool filled) : base(color, filled)
        {
            this.point1 = point1;
            this.point2 = point2;
            this.point3 = point3;
        }
    }
```

The idea here is that `Triangle`, if initialized with `color` and `filling` should override the inherited ones, otherwise should implement the logic from a parent class and basically fall to default values.

I got an error, and Visual Studio suggests me to add another constructor to `Shape` that would do this:

```
public Shape(string color, bool filled)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.filled = filled;
        }
```

Would this be the right thing to do? I just have a feeling that adding another constructor for each case kinda undermines the principles of code reuse, and there should be a better and more elegant solution. Looking around at SO didn't help me find an actual answer.

What would be a good practice/the best solution here?

Comment: In the `Triangle` class the constructor call the base constructor with only color and bool which you don't have. That is why it's asking you to create the constructor as it doesnt exist

Comment: Note that there is also no need to create a `Point` class as it already exist as `System.Drawing.Point`

Comment: @Franck so it would be a good practice to design a code this way - to create an additional constructor for specific use cases? Or is it considered bad for creating extra code and if possible, solutions should be found to avoid this?

Comment: No as you can use the existing one. Check @CodeCaster answer that is exactly how it should be

Comment: Note that second constructor you have can be rewritten to be `public Shape(Point[] points) : this(points, "green", true) {}` so you are not duplicating code.

Comment: Based on your requirements, you ask yourself how many different ways does the object need to be constructed and you supply constructors for it. Make sure the object is valid once constructed. The other approach is to create an object and then supply the parameters by setting properties. There are many approaches and you need to choose one based on your needs. Try to utilize existing constructors for new constructors to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Are you sure you have an appropriate abstraction? A line should probably be a shape, but can it be filled? If you have a Axis Aligned rectangle, would the points describe each corner? Top left + Bottom right corner? Center + size? If the base class lacks public properties/methods, why place the fields in the base class rather than the derived class? I would suggest minimizing fields in the base class, and add abstract methods for specific use cases, like `GetArea`, or `Draw`. You could also consider separating the shapes themselves from code that is only relevant for drawing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to redefine the three points that form a triangle: the Shape class can already save those, namely in its points array.

So initialize that array and pass it to the parent:

```
class Triangle : Shape
{
    public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3, string color, bool filled) 
        : base(new [] { point1, point2, point3 }, color, filled)
    {
    }
}
```

Then when you want to do something with the points within the triangle, you just use `base.points[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` respectively.

This illustrates the problem the compiler informs you about: you need to call an **existing base constructor**. There's no base constructor without a points array, so the IDE suggests to generate one. But that's not what you actually want.

Comment: So it's generally better to follow this approach than add new constructors for every new use case?

Comment: This is more for sanity reason. If you end up creating 1 constructor for each combinaison your derived classes has, you could end up with thousands of constructors and it would be a nightmare to maintain. For the code itself it is a insignificant performance impact (to create many constructors) so it really come down to maintainability.

Comment: @Danylo you use base/parent/super classes to abstract away common behavior and properties. As soon as they're not common anymore, it probably doesn't belong in that base class.